# Cannot read Part's content (Flux<DataBuffer>) into a single String

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

In the following snippet, I'm trying to extract a file's content (sent to a given service) using Spring's Part object and convert it into a String.

The issue is that it skips the mapper function and the code inside the mapper function doesn't execute like the filePartMono's content is empty, but when I inspect the object at runtime , its storage field has the file's data.

```
public void parseFilePart(Part filePartMono) {
    filePartMono.content().map(dataBuffer -> {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
            dataBuffer.read(bytes);
            DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
            String fileContent = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        });
}
```

Comment: why is the function void? what is calling this function. You should not have void functions, you need to return something so that the calling code can chain on. Please post the code calling this function.

Comment: The method should return some Mono<String>, but even with that return type it behaves the same. the void is just for testing purpose.

Answer (score 3):

`org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.Part.content()` returns a `Flux<DataBuffer>`, meaning nothing happens until you subscribe to this `Publisher`.

**If your code can be executed in a blocking way** without causing errors, you can refactor it like this to get the String result:

```java
public void parseFilePart(Part filePartMono) {
  List<String> parts = 
    filePartMono.content()
    .map(dataBuffer -> {
          byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
          dataBuffer.read(bytes);
          DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
          return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    })
    .collectList()
    .block();
  //do what you want here with the Strings you retrieved
}
```

If you're sure that the `Flux<DataBuffer>` will always emit 1 single `DataBuffer`, you can replace `.collectList().block()` with `.blockFirst()` and obtain a `String` result instead of `List<String>`.

**If your code can't be executed in a blocking fashion**, then you could refactor it like this:

```java
public void parseFilePart(Part filePartMono) {
    filePartMono.content()
    .map(dataBuffer -> {
          byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
          dataBuffer.read(bytes);
          DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
          return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    })
    .subscribe(resultString -> {
      //do what you want with the result String here
    });
}
```

*P.S. I didn't test your implementation to convert `DataBuffer` to `String`, so you might have to double-check that now that it's actually invoked*

Comment: Your suggestion throws: java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-7

Comment: Then you can't execute blocking code on that thread, I'll refactor the answer to be fully reactive then.

Comment: Still not working. it skips also the code block of the consumer and exit the method immediately

Comment: Seems like the source is empty but it's not. this solution works https://manhtai.github.io/posts/flux-databuffer-to-inputstream/ . but I'd like to understand what's wrong with mine...

Comment: subscribe is aysnc,may not get no data